# Keep website from adjusting to window-size

Tags: html

I think I have a VERY basic question here. I've been trying to figure this out for a while now: I'm working with an html-template called "Oyster HTML" and I've been trying to disable all functions (or css) that make the site adjust to the window size.

This is the link to the demo of the template: 
http://www.gt3themes.com/website-templates/oyster/portfolio_masonry_listing.html

As you decrease the window's width in your browser, you'll see that - for example on the right side of the header - the menu-content adjusts. (doesn't get overlapped)

Same thing happens here: https://learn.wu.ac.at

Now, on 'common' websites like www.ebay.com this is not the case (content gets overlapped by window and doesn't adjust to window resize)

My question: Is this a JavaScript issue? or CSS? (I tried disabling all .js and all .css but the content **still** adjusted.) Now if it's not in JS or CSS, where can I change this?

As I said, this might be a very basic (or even dumb) question, but I've been trying to wrap my mind around this for quite some time now, and I just couldn't figure it out)

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding your question, but if it that what I think, you are talking about CSS. This is the responsive.css in your site, what is controlling, what should happens on different device screen sizes. Are you want to remove that? (I guess no, because a lots of people brows the sites from mobile devices).

Comment: I tried removing responsive.css along with all other .css files. 

Do you understand what I mean? Open both "https://learn.wu.ac.at" and "www.ebay.com" and decrease your browser window's width to the minimum and compare the results. 

I can't get rid of this phenomenon on my site. (I need it to be like on ebay.com)